# Removing Dimmer Switch, 3 wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

I want to remove a dimmer switch and cap off the wires. This switch will no longer be used - my question - I have two black hot wires and a red wire.  I believe the black wires will be capped together but what about the red wire? In this instance the white wires are capped off and in the background. This room has two switches thus the irregular configuration. To be more clear - I am putting a flat plate over the box because we are moving a large cabinet in that spot - so I just want to cap off the wires correctly.

[image]

Comment: Is this dimmer a part of a 3-way switch configuration where another switch also controls the lights?

Comment: @brhans - Yes that's correct

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Identify which two wires are the messengers and which is the common.

You would rely on markings on the old dimmer switch for that.

You can also look in the back of the box to see how the wires group in conduit or cable: if two are in one cable and the third is not, the two together are the messengers.

2. Join one messenger and the common.

If the other switch(es) now turn on in a position you don't like, use the other messenger.

3. Cap off the unused messenger.

It *will* be hot whenever the light is off!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just connect the two blacks together and cap off securely the red.  Now you can cover over this box.

Comment: Great Thanks Paul!  Ok, I have one little issue now - the remaining switch operates the light but down is on and up is off -  It looks like it has the red wire and two black wires attached also.  Any suggestions appreciated - Thanks

Comment: OK. Now connect the red wire to the black that exits a different cable.  Securely cap the other black.