# Remove 3-Way Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

I know this has been asked before, but I just want to be clear on 1. what I need to test in order to be sure which box has the hot wire, and 2. the wiring steps to remove the second box. Many thanks!

Phillip

[image]

Comment: We need to see pictures of the boxes, there are multiple ways to wire a 3-way and we can't tell from here which you happen to have.   Also how eliminated do you want?  Is leaving a junction box ok? Or does this need to be removed completely to make way for something else?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the box or just remove the 3 way switch?

Comment: I thought I gave a  [very good step-by-step](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/127189/47125) on this last week. But lots of room for a good answer to address the *other* considerations here.  Also +1 for using Excel as a drawing program. Very minecraft.  Additionally, first rule of 3-ways, ignore wire colors, and especially ignore wire positions.  **Look at the screw colors**, they define everything.

Comment: I'm just trying to remove the three way switch, not the box - I'll put a blank faceplate over it.